# Find CVE of all Debian based linux Packages?

Tags: debian

**Is there anyway through which we can get all CVE  Debian based Packages?**

Any scanner or command which shows outdated packages in the system & their CVE's (if available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`debsecan`](https://packages.debian.org/debsecan) will do this. To install it, run

```
sudo apt install debsecan
```

which will ask you a few configuration questions; once that’s finished,

```
debsecan
```

will show all the open CVEs in installed packages on the system.

You can see CVEs for which fixes are available by specifying the relevant suite:

```
debsecan --only-fixed --suite buster
```

Each CVE will have further details on [the Debian security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/), including comments for packages which won’t be fixed.

The tool can be configured to run periodically and email reports too.